# Listen to socket on a specific port number as a client

Tags: android, sockets, client, inputstream

I want to know how to listen to a specific port when the application is client for example; IP:127.0.0.1 and port number 12345. There is a windows application which can listen to incoming data from server in every 2 minutes but Inputstrem doesn't act to server data at all. It only works whenever I send request codes to server. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

**This is my receiver code:**

```
private void receiveData(){
    // Again, probably better to store these objects references in the support class
    if(getSocket() != null && getSocket().isConnected()){
        try {
            Log.i("Log", "Ready to receive!");
            byte[] buffer  = new byte[8192];
            final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead );
                rec_buffer = baos.toByteArray();
                for (int i = 0; i< size; i++)
                    //Log.i("Log", "Data i: " + rec_buffer[i]);
                    Log.i("Log", "Data i: " + String.format("0x%20x", rec_buffer[i]));
                mResponseHandler.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        if(mCallback != null){
                            baos.reset();
                            mCallback.onDataReceived(rec_buffer);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Log", "Error occured during receiving data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Android's [`Socket`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket) class has 2 constructors that let you specify a `localAddr` and `localPort` to bind the client to when making a connection to a remote server.  That being said, your example refers to an HTTP url.  HTTP is a request/response protocol. You can't get a response from the server without sending a request to it first.  So, what are you REALLY trying to accomplish?  Please be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have to connect to a port with specific IP, it was just a simple of port and IP. The point is I can connect to server via socket but I have to listen to incoming data too. Server sends an update packet in every 2 minutes but Inputstream doesn't act to incoming data. I can only receive data when I send a request to server.

Comment: what is the actual protocol you are working with, because it is obviously not HTTP. Without that important detail, nobody can tell you why you are not getting any data. And why are you using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` at all? You dont need it

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your negative point, Actually I need `ByteArrayOutputStream` because whenever I send request to server it sends its data separately and I only can collect data with this. Thanks for your advice, I gonna change my question.

Comment: I'm not being negative, I'm being real. You have not provided enough details to help you,so your question is likely to get closed as off-topic. And no, `ByteArrayOutputStream` is not the only way to collect data. Given the code you have shown, all you are doing is copying bytes from one `byte[]` array to another. You don't need `ByteArrayOutputStream` to do that.